# execvp with "ls" not working in custom shell

Tags: c, unix

**What I am doing**: Creating a custom shell for a class project. Just started implementing my fork and exec features.

**My Issue**:  `ls` works fine until I change directories with `cd`. After the first `cd`, `ls` requires the `.` to list files in current directory. After that, it seems to lose all functionality.

I've included my code below. Any help (including pointing out obvious newb mistakes) is appreciated. I am in the early stages of grasping these concepts.

```
int main(){
  char *input = malloc(sizeof(char*) * BUFFERSIZE);
  char *token;
  char **token_array;
  int i;
  int return_status;

  printf("%s", BOILERPLATE);  
  if (input == NULL){
    printf("JASH: Buffer Allocation Failed");
    return 1;
  }

  // Shell Loop
  while(1){
    i = 0;

    printf("JASH:>  ");
    fgets(input, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
    token_array = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(input));

    token = strtok(input, " \n()<>|&;");
    while(token != NULL){
      token_array[i] = token;
      token = strtok(NULL, " \n()<>|&;");
      i++;
    }

    // print tokens to confirm correct parsing of input
    printf("%s : %s\n", token_array[0], token_array[1]);

    //printf("%s\n", token_array[0]);
    if(exec_args(token_array) == 0){
      // programm exit successfully
      free(token_array);
      free(input);
      return 0;;
    }

  } // Loop End




  // free input buffer before exit
  free(token_array);
  free(input);
  return 0;

}


int exec_args(char ** t){
  int i;

  if(strcmp(t[0], "exit") == 0
     || strcmp(t[0], "quit") == 0
     || strcmp(t[0], "logout") == 0){
    // call built in function for exit
    exit(0);
  }

  if (strcmp(t[0], "cd") == 0){
    // call built in function for chdir
    if(chdir(t[1]) == 0){
      printf("Successfully changed directories to %s\n", t[1]);
      return 1;
    } else {
      printf("-JASH: cd: %s: No such file or directory\n", t[1]);
      return 1;
    }
  } 

  if (strcmp(t[0], "pwd") == 0) {
    char * p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);
    getcwd(p, 100);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    free(p);
    return 1;
  } 

  if(strcmp(t[0], "help") == 0){
    printf("\n%s\n Help Documentation Coming soon!\n\n", BOILERPLATE);
    return 1;
  } 


  if(fork() == 0){
   if(execvp(t[0], t)){
     perror("JASH");
   } 

  } else {
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    printf("%d", status);
  }
  return 1;

}
```

Comment: noted:

Update: Fixed..  Moved "free(token_array)" outside of my shell while loop.

Comment: `token_array = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(input))` should be `sizeof(char *)`, since you're allocating an array of pointers.

Comment: If `chdir` fails due to a permission error, an error message of the form 'No such file or directory' (written to stdout!) is less than helpful.  `man perror`

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn also to use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), in particular to understand what *existing* shells are doing. Study the source code of free software shells, such as `sash` or `bash`, for inspiration

Comment: You're not adding a NULL value at the end of the array of tokens, as required by execvp.